# printf() functionality in Java combined with a CharBuffer or something like it

Tags: java, stream, printf

I am a little confused here.

I would like to do something like this:

1. create some kind of buffer I can write into
2. clear the buffer
3. use a printf()-like function several times to append a bunch of stuff into the buffer based on some complicated calculations I only want to do once
4. use the contents of the buffer and print it to several `PrintStream` objects
5. repeat steps 2-4 as necessary

e.g.:

```
SuperBuffer sb = new SuperBuffer();
  /* SuperBuffer is not a real class, so I don't know what to use here */
PrintStream[] streams = new PrintStream[N];
/* ... initialize this array to several streams ... */

while (!done)
{
    sb.clear();
    sb.printf("something %d something %d something %d", 
        value1, value2, value3);
    if (some_complicated_condition())
        sb.printf("something else %d something else %d", value4, value5);
    /* ... more printfs to sb ... */
    for (PrintStream ps : streams)
        ps.println(sb.getBuffer());
}
```

It looks like wrapping a [PrintWriter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) around [StringWriter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) will do what I want for the `sb` object above, except there's no `clear()` method. I suppose I could create a new PrintWriter and StringWriter object each time through the loop, but that seems like a pain. (in my real code I do this in several places, not just once in one loop...)

I've also used `java.nio.CharBuffer` and other NIO buffers a lot, and that seems like a promising approach, but I'm not sure how I can wrap them with an object that will give me `printf()` functionality.

any advice?

Comment: What exactly is it you want to do, what are you trying and how is it not working? Please clarify your question, I really don't understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ah: I think I've got it. The [`Formatter`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class has a `format()` method that's like `printf()`, and it can be constructed to wrap around any kind of object that implements `Appendable`. [`CharBuffer`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html) implements `Appendable`, and I can `clear()` or read out the contents of the `CharBuffer` as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it a pain to create a new buffer in the loop? That's what the garbage collector is there for. There would need to be a new allocation under the covers in clear() anyway.

If you really want to implement your SuperBuffer, it would not be that hard at all. Just create a subclass of OutputStream with a clear() function, and then wrap a PrintStream around that.  You could use a CharBuffer in your super buffer if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a subclass, TeeOutputStream, of OutputStream (or Writer) that holds your array of streams and delegates to them. Then wrap your stream with a PrintStream (or PrintWriter) and just call printf() on it. No need for a temp buffer or anything:

```
PrintStream[] streams = new PrintStream[N]; // any output streams really
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new TeeOutputStream(streams));

while (!done)
{
    ps.printf("something %d something %d something %d",
              value1, value2, value3);    
    if (some_complicated_condition())
        ps.printf("something else %d something else %d", value4, value5);
    ps.println();
}
```